# PHP PDO not inserting or throwing error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, insert

The email is not being inserted into the database, however I am receiving an echo of success without any errors. I'm not sure what is going wrong. I've tried it with a duplicate email and I get the duplicate email message so it is connecting to the database, and it will not insert when it is a duplicate; however, it seems to not be inserting anything when it is not a duplicate. It seems to just skip the step of uploading.

```
<?php
include 'db_functions.php';
$_POST['email'] = 'somenewemail@gmail.com';
if(isset($_POST['email']) && ($_POST['email'] != NULL || $_POST['email'] != '')){
    $ERRORS = array();
    $cleanEmail = htmlentities($_POST['email']);

    $database = dbconnlocal();
    $queryEmailExists = $database->prepare("SELECT email FROM email_list WHERE email= ?");
    $queryUploadEmail = $database->prepare("INSERT INTO email_list (email) VALUES ( ? )");

    $database->beginTransaction();
    try 
    {
        $queryEmailExists->execute(array($cleanEmail));
        $results = $queryEmailExists->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $dbEmail = $results[0]['email'];

        if(trim($dbEmail) == trim($cleanEmail)) {
            // duplicate email
            throw new Exception('duplicateEmail');
        } else {
            // new email
            $queryUploadEmail->execute(array($cleanEmail));
            echo json_encode('success');
        }

    } 
    catch (Exception $e) 
    {
        switch(trim($e->getMessage())) {
            case 'duplicateEmail':
                // handle duplicate error   
                $ERRORS['error'] = 'duplicateEmail';
                break;
            default:
                // handle default errors
                $ERRORS['error'] = 'default';
                break;
        }
            echo json_encode($ERRORS['error']);
    }
} else { echo json_encode('emptyEmail'); /* empty email */ };
```

?>

Comment: If there's no matching email, `fetchAll()` will return an empty array, so there's no `$results[0]`. You should check `if(empty($results))`

Comment: Have you enabled `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`?